# How do I make 33% "list view" in Nautilus be the default view for the system?

Tags: nautilus, personalization

How do I make 33% "list view" in Nautilus be the default view for the system?

If there isn't a way, another thought I am questioning:  Is there a way to set a view to go recursive into all child folders?   What if I want my Music folder to have a certain style of view permanently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From within Nautilus navigate the menus to Edit->Preferences.

On the main Views tab change the "View new folders using" option to "List View" and the "Default zoom level" option at the bottom to 33%.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: To add to fluteflute's excellent answer, I must say that sometimes this does not work for me for some directories, even after waiting for changes to take effect. In this case I manually change it using the menu already visible in that particular directory.

Comment: Alright, that seems to be working but it wasn't work when I asked the question earlier.  Not sure what I did that it appeared to be broken.

Answer (score 8):

Addendum to [fluteflute's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21724/how-do-i-make-33-list-view-in-nautilus-be-the-default-view-for-the-system/21727#21727):

If you want to delete previously saved (per-folder) views, you can delete the files in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata`. Next time you start Nautilus, all folders should use the view type you set in the preferences.

Comment: Any chance you could just edit this into the body of the other answer for completeness? [Same thing here](http://askubuntu.com/a/34683/12864), if you're feeling frisky. I think the second one got merged and could use a bit more merging. Thanks.