# Let nautilus use the same view for all folders?

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make “compact view” as a default directory view instead of “icon view”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34644/make-compact-view-as-a-default-directory-view-instead-of-icon-view)

Is it possible to let nautilus use same view (icon/list/compact) for all folders?

I didn't seem to find it in Preference dialog