# How to sort files inside a directory via terminal?

Tags: nautilus

I want to sort subdirectories inside a main directory according to the size,and also I want to sort files inside the subdirectories according to the file created date through terminal. Is that possible?

**Edit**: After I sorted the files inside the folder by following the below answers, it doesn't rearranges while I am viewing through nautilus. I want the files to be rearranged while viewing it through nautilus.

Comment: Sorry, but either, you make that nautilus arrange them or you do using the terminal, there isn't a middle point between them,

Comment: Related: [Setting the view mode recursively for a directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335874/how-do-i-recursively-set-the-nautilus-view-mode-for-a-directory-tree)

Comment: what i needed was posted by @souravc.

Comment: You cannot sort files in a terminal and expect them to remain sorted when viewing them in nautilus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort sub-directories/files inside a directory according to the size, type in terminal,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order "size"
```

To sort sub-directories/files according to file modification time,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-order "mtime"
```

You can also sort according to `name` and `type`. But you can not set two values simultaneously, like one for a directory and other for sub-directories. There is no problem to change the values any time. The change will take place immediately for all directories.

Also you can [sort in reverse order](https://askubuntu.com/a/360305/127327) for `size`, `name`, `modification time` or `type`. To do this type in terminal,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-sort-in-reverse-order true
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort the files according to the size you can use the following command:

```
ls -Sl
```

To sort the results by date created is a little bit more complicated. See the following post in this sense:

- [How do I do a ls and then sort the results by date created?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20460/37944)

Comment: it only list the files according to the size,not rearranged according to the size.

Comment: If you want that the files to be arranged according to the size every time when you run `ls`, then use an alias as follow: `alias ls='ls -S'`.

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and type as

```
du -sk * | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible without a loop – at least not in bash – but if you're willing to use loops, here's an example that will get you on the right track.

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in $(du -sh */ | sort -rh | cut -f2); do
    echo "*** $(du -sh $dir) ***"
    ls -l --sort=time $dir
done
```

This script …

- loops over all entries of `du -sh`, sorted by size – `cut` just formats the output
- and, for each entry, prints the total size of that directory (`du -sh`) and lists its content sorted by size (`ls -l --sort=time`).

Comment: `ls -l --sort=time` will sort files according to the **modified** date, not **created** date.

Comment: You're right, but unfortunately most unix FS don't save creation time, so `--sort=time` is as good as it gets. For more detailed information, check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created